# Why is my obj file imported into pyglet showing a blank screen?

Tags: obj, pyglet

I am trying to figure out how to import .obj files generated using Blender into my Pyglet game. There is an [importer object](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/contrib/model/model/obj.py?name=enhancements_1_2), [example code](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/contrib/model/examples/obj_test.py?name=enhancements_1_2), and an example [.obj](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/contrib/model/examples/rabbit.obj?name=enhancements_1_2)/[.mtl](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/contrib/model/examples/rabbit.mtl?name=enhancements_1_2) file within Pyglet's contrib directory.

The pyglet contrib version works (and is flickery; comment out `w.flip`) with the pyglet/contrib .obj/.mtl files. When I try to run it with **my** [.obj](https://raw.github.com/greenmoss/pyglet_obj_test/master/asteroid.obj) and [.mtl](https://raw.github.com/greenmoss/pyglet_obj_test/master/asteroid.mtl) files I get a blank screen.

Why am I seeing a blank screen instead of my Blender-generated object?

FWIW, [here's my test repo](https://github.com/greenmoss/pyglet_obj_test).

Comment: "Debug my code for me" questions are really too localised for this site.  Your best bet is to teach yourself to use a debugger, and trace through your program's execution yourself to work out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were no normals, so nothing was displaying. I updated the git repo to warn on missing normals.

Unfortunately, I have no ground-breaking debugging techniques to report. I opened up the working .obj file and the "broken" .obj file, and by comparing them I noticed that one of the files had normals, and the other one didn't.